# Jquery mobile popup ui-popup-screen not following when scrolled

Tags: jquery-mobile, popup

I have a JQM 1.3 popup which I have set to data-dismissible="true"  All is good until the screen is scrolled.  The popup scrolls fine and I have a javascript event listener to center the popup when the scrolling stops. The problem is that the underlying -screen div (that jqm creates) does not follow the popup.  So if I scroll to the bottom of the screen and then click anywhere outside of the popup it does not dismiss the popup.  Using the dev tools I can see that the css for the -screen div never changes after the popup is displayed.

I want the -screen div to track my popup div so that regardless of where I scroll to - anywhere that I click outside of the popup it will dismiss it.  Currently if I want to click outside the popup to dismiss it I have to scroll the screen back up to where the popup was first displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:
When I was appending the popup I was not appending it down far enough in the DOM. I was appending the popup to 'body' and instead it needs to be appended one level down to the div with data-role="page" or the div with class 'ui-page' set.

The popup is contained within a handlebars template:

```
$('body .ui-page-active').append(template());
```